JPA is duplicating a column when inserting. Multiple columns as primary and foreign key
JPA is duplicating a column when trying to insert (column active) and it does not insert the value in one of the parameter.
The error is the following:
could not execute statement [No value specified for parameter 6.] 
[insert into payment_item 
(account_id,x,y,active,payment_id,active,id) 
values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)]

The DDL is the followinng (simplfied for the explanation):
CREATE TABLE payment_item (
    id BIGINT,
    payment_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
    active BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true ,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, active),
    FOREIGN KEY (payment_id, active) REFERENCES payment (id, active)
) PARTITION BY LIST (active);

The mapping jpa:
public class PaymentItemKey implements Serializable {
    private Long id;

    private Boolean active = true;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_item")
@IdClass(PaymentItemKey.class)
public class PaymentItemEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "payment_item_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "payment_item_generator", sequenceName = "payment_item_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private boolean active = true;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "active", referencedColumnName = "active")
    })
    private PaymentEntity payment;

}

if only works if I remove active from the primary key. But it is necessary because I want to partition the table using active column
Note that if I use Embedded instead of IdClass it gives the same error.

the "active" column seems a part of your FK and your primary key. I don't think this is a good idea to be honest, as this model has a unique ID assigned for each entry - it will be difficult to have two entries with the same ID with one being active=true and the other active=false. You shouldn't attempt to use mutable values in an entity, and probably should just be using the ID values in the PK and FK values

Hi @Ch
Thanks for your help. I use active as Primary because I want to partition the table by active column. I don't know if it is the best approach, but in this one I need to put active as primary Key

The way to solve this is to mark one of the columns as read-only - JPA allows marking the joinColumn as insertable=false, updatable=false which would allow you to control the column entirely though the boolean property, but also require you to set it yourself (it might not work if using Hibernate, and I cannot check). Note though that it will cause complexity if you try to toggle that column value - you'll have to do so on all objects in the PaymentEntity graph.

@Chris, I have tried use insertable and updatable false, but It did no work.
The solution Andrey gave worked for me.
Thanks for your help

This error occurs because you are trying to declare two different columns with the same name. One column is declared in the code private boolean active = true;, the second column is declared in the code @JoinColumn(name = "active", referencedColumnName = "active"). To solve the problem you need to get rid of one of the columns or use a different name.
I suggest you get rid of the field in the code private boolean active = true;. Since the Payment entity is related to PaymentItem by a one-to-many relationship, its active field is propagated to each nested item.
As a result, we get the following mapping.
@Entity
@IdClass(PaymentKey.class)
@Table(name = "payments")
public class Payment {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Id
    private Boolean active;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "payment", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<PaymentItem> items;

  // ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "payment_items")
public class PaymentItem {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonBackReference
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "active", referencedColumnName = "active")
    })
    private Payment payment;

  // ...
}

public class PaymentKey implements Serializable {
    
    private Long id;
    
    private Boolean active;
    
  // ...
}



Thanks for you help.
I have tried remove the active column, but since it is a primary key it gives the error "PaymentItemEntity' has an '@IdClass' with properties 'active' which do not match properties of the entity class"

Using a different name does not works also. Because if I rename payment_item.active column to active2, it stills have active2 twice in the class

@Mark If you remove private boolean active from PaymentItemEntity, you need to remove it from PaymentItemKey as well, see my code. If you decide to use different names, you need to have the field name in private boolean active different from the field name in @JoinColumn(name = "active", referencedColumnName = "active").

Finnaly it worked.
I keep id and active as a primary key in payment_item and I remove active from PaymentItemKey and PaymentItem and now is working fine.
In my point of view, it is at least strange to have a composite primary key and not be able to include one of the fields with the  @ Id annotation, but that's okay, the important thing is that it works
Thank you a lot
